# How to create graph using adjacency matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graph

I find the adjacency from an image, then I'm trying to draw the graph using the graph function:

```
g = graph(adj); 
plot(g);
```

but I'm not getting the expected graph.

Input image

[image: input image]

This is my code. I am storing the adjacency matrix in the variable `adj`.

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
X=imread('one.bmp');
imfinfo('one.bmp')
figure,imshow(X)

b = imresize(X,[100,100]);
si = size(b,1);
sj = size(b,2);
%figure;imshow(b);

% Binarization
% th = graythresh(b);
% I = im2bw(b,th);
%thinning
kl=bwmorph(~b,'thin',inf);
figure,imshow(kl)
R(:,:)=kl(:,:);
%grid size 
t1=25;
D=100;
 I=1;
U1=t1;
J=1;
U2=t1;
E=1;
t2=D/t1;
%Z=1;
for iir=1:t2
    for jjr=1:t2
 B(I:U1,J:U2)=R(I:U1,J:U2);
%  vc=sum(B(I:U1,J:U2));
%  Fd=sum(vc);
 [x,y]=find(B==1);
 CX=mean(x);
 CY=mean(y);
 CXXX(E)=CX;
 CYYY(E)=CY;
 CXX(iir,jjr)=CX;
 CYY(iir,jjr)=CY;

 T(I:U1,J:U2)=B(I:U1,J:U2);
    J=J+t1;
  U2=U2+t1;
E=E+1;
 clear B x y 

    end

I=I+t1;
U1=U1+t1;
J=1;
  U2=t1;

end
%plot and grid
figure,imshow(R)
hold on
M10 = size(R,1);
N10 = size(R,2);

a=t1; 
b=t1;
for k = 1:a:M10
    x = [1 N10]; 
   y = [k k]; 
   plot(x,y,'Color','white');
    set(findobj('Tag','MyGrid'),'Visible','on')
end
for k = 1:b:N10 
    x = [k k]; 
    y = [1 M10];
    plot(x,y,'Color','white');
    set(findobj('Tag','MyGrid'),'Visible','on')
end

plot(CYY,CXX,'g*')
%line(CYY,CXX)
%CC=bwconncomp(CXX,4)

hold off
%node neighbourhoood analyssis
N1=t2;
for I2=1:N1
    for J2=1:N1
        %last row
       if(I2>=N1)
             W1=CXX(I2,J2);
           W2=CXX(I2-1,J2);
           W3=CYY(I2,J2);
           W4=CYY(I2-1,J2);    
           W6=[W1,W2];
           W7=[W3,W4];
           line(W7,W6);
           if(J2>=N1)
               Z=CXX(I2,J2);
           else
           if (CXX(I2,J2+1)>1)&& ((CYY(I2,J2+1)>1))
            TXX=CXX(I2,J2);
            TYY=CXX(I2,J2+1);
               TTX=CYY(I2,J2);
               TTY=CYY(I2,J2+1);

            IY=[TXX,TYY];
            IIY=[TTX,TTY];
            line(IIY,IY);
           end
           end


       else
           if(J2>=N1);
             W1=CXX(I2,J2);
           W2=CXX(I2+1,J2);
           W3=CYY(I2,J2);
           W4=CYY(I2+1,J2);    
           W6=[W1,W2];
           W7=[W3,W4];
           line(W7,W6);
           else   
               if (CXX(I2,J2+1)>1)&& ((CYY(I2,J2+1)>1))
            TXX=CXX(I2,J2);
            TYY=CXX(I2,J2+1);
               TTX=CYY(I2,J2);
               TTY=CYY(I2,J2+1);

            IY=[TXX,TYY];
            IIY=[TTX,TTY];
            line(IIY,IY);


               end
         if (CXX(I2+1,J2)>1)&& ((CYY(I2+1,J2)>1))
           W1=CXX(I2,J2);
           W2=CXX(I2+1,J2);
           W3=CYY(I2,J2);
           W4=CYY(I2+1,J2);    
           W6=[W1,W2];
           W7=[W3,W4];
           line(W7,W6);
           J2=J2+1

         end
        end
    end
    end
end

    A=zeros(t2,t2);   
    ttt=1;
   for rt=1:t2
      for  rt1=1:t2
          if(CXX(rt,rt1)>1)
              A(rt,rt1)=ttt
          end
          ttt=ttt+1;
      end
   end



g=1;
jk=1;
um=t2-1;
um1=t2;
for iir=1:t2
    for jjr=1:t2
        if(A(iir,jjr)>=0)
            BB(jk)=0;
                       DD(g)=0;
                      FF(g)=0;
                      HH(g)=0;
        end
        if(A(iir,jjr)>=1)
          if(iir==um1)&&(jjr==1)
             GG(g)=A(iir,jjr);
            HH(g)=A(iir-1,jjr); 
            BB(jk)=A(iir,jjr+1);
            DD(g)=0;
          else
              if(iir==um1)&&(jjr>1)&&(jjr<=um)
               FF(g)=A(iir,jjr-1); 
                BB(jk)=A(iir,jjr+1);
                HH(g)=A(iir-1,jjr);
              else

              if(iir==um1)&&(jjr==um1)
                  HH(g)=A(iir-1,jjr);
                  FF(g)=A(iir,jjr-1);
                  DD(g)=0;
                  BB(jk)=0;
              else

        if(iir==1)&&(jjr==um1)
            FF(g)=A(iir,jjr-1);
            DD(g)=A(iir+1,jjr);
            BB(jk)=0;

        else
            if(iir>=1)&&(iir<=um)&&(jjr==um1)
             HH(g)=A(iir-1,jjr);
             DD(g)=A(iir+1,jjr);
            FF(g)=A(iir,jjr-1);
            BB(jk)=0;
            else
              if(iir==1)&&(jjr==1)
                BB(jk)=A(iir,jjr+1);  
                DD(g)=A(iir+1,jjr);
              else
              if(iir==1)&&(jjr>=1)&&(jjr<=um)  
              FF(g)=A(iir,jjr-1);    
              DD(g)=A(iir+1,jjr); 
                BB(jk)=A(iir,jjr+1);
              else
               if(iir>1)&&(iir<=um)&&(jjr==1)   
                HH(g)=A(iir-1,jjr);
                DD(g)=A(iir+1,jjr);
                BB(jk)=A(iir,jjr+1);
               else
                   if(iir>1)&&(iir<=um)&&(jjr>1)&&(jjr<=um) 
                       BB(jk)=A(iir,jjr+1);
                   DD(g)=A(iir+1,jjr);
                   HH(g)=A(iir-1,jjr);
                    FF(g)=A(iir,jjr-1);
                   end
               end
              end
              end
            end
        end
              end
          end
          end
        end
    g=g+1;
    jk=jk+1;
    end

end
adj=zeros(t2*t2);
H9=size(adj);
Y=1;
for ll=1:1
        for ii=1:H9(1,1)
            for jj=1:H9(1,1)
                if (ii>=4)
                    if (jj==DD(1,Y))
                    adj(ii,jj)=1;
                end
                if (jj==FF(1,Y))
                    adj(ii,jj)=1;
                end
                if (jj==BB(1,Y))
                    adj(ii,jj)=1;
                end
                if (jj==HH(1,Y))
                    adj(ii,jj)=1;
                end
                else
                if (jj==BB(1,Y))
                    adj(ii,jj)=1;
                end
                if (jj==DD(1,Y))
                    adj(ii,jj)=1;
                end
                if (jj==FF(1,Y))
                    adj(ii,jj)=1;
                end
                if (jj==HH(1,Y))
                    adj(ii,jj)=1;
                end
                end
            end
            Y=Y+1;
        end

end
```

Expected output:

[image: i want graph in this form]

adjacency matrix

```
0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: How are you getting the adjacency matrix? What is it supposed to represent? Pixel adjacency? There are not enough entries to represent all your pixels. Connected component adjacency? Your input image looks fully connected, so there are too many entries. Please add more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the graph object does not know anything about the location of the points you're trying to plot. You need to use the centroid coordinates to determine where to plot the edges from the adjacency matrix.

Assuming the centroids of the points in the adjacency matrix are given by `CX` and `CY`, you need to pass this information to the `plot` function.

```
g = graph(adj); 
plot(g, 'XData', CX, 'YData', CY);
```

See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.plot.html

Comment: can you please give me the full code of this program

Comment: This *is* the full code. The only thing that I've left out is assigning your adjacency matrix to the variable `A`. You just need to replace the `CX` and `CY` variables with the coordinates corresponding to each graph node.

Comment: And be sure to say hi to shivu and raghu for me. :)

Comment: i do not know how to replace the CX and CY variables with the coordinates corresponding to each graph node

Comment: You've already calculated the centroids, right? And then determined the connectivity between those centroids in `adj`. So you should know which node in `adj` is associated with each centroid.

Comment: how to determine the connectivity between those centroids

Comment: Thank you Mr.beaker after plotting how can i covert plotted figure as graph??. is there any method to convert the plotted figure as graph?

Comment: i am just plotting, i want to convert that plotted image as graph please help me.